# Not able to login to oracle using sqlplus utility because username and password contain space

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Using oracle SQL Plus command prompt i able to login with user "p 6".
for login connect command is used.
[image]

but i want to login with sqlplus command line utility and using window command prompt.
but it not working due to space in username and password. i tried many thing double quote, single quote, / etc.
does not work.
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be using usernames with spaces in, basically. Tom Kyte eludes to it here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:595223460734 - But basically you shouldn't be creating a username that would have to be a quoted identifier

Comment: I do not see any error message, `fail` is a vague description. Usernames are case-sensitive. `user2` and `"user2"` are different users. The first one is automatically converted to uppercase (`USER2`), while the second one remains lowercase because of the quoting marks, so I would not be surprised, if you received an `ORA-01017`.

Comment: please post text  input/output as text (e.g. between <pre></pre> tags and not as screenshots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
C:\Users\balaz>sqlplus bp/bp@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 28 15:51:40 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Sep 28 2016 15:51:30 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics,
Real Application Testing and Unified Auditing options

SQL> create user "U 1" identified by "PASS WORD";

User created.

SQL> grant create session to "U 1";

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics,
Real Application Testing and Unified Auditing options

C:\Users\balaz>sqlplus \""U 1"\"/\""PASS WORD"\"@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Sep 28 15:52:07 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics,
Real Application Testing and Unified Auditing options

SQL> show user
USER is "U 1"
SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a sqlplus /nolog then connect. That should work.

```
SQL> create user bob identified by "     ";

User created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
SQL> grant connect, create session to bob;

Grant succeeded.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
SQL> connect bob/"     "
Connected.
SQL > show user
USER is "BOB"
SQL > exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Sep 28 09:25:28 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

@ > connect bob/"     "
Connected.
SQL > show user
USER is "BOB"
```

Comment: The screenshot in the question shows that it's possible to connect once already in sqlplus itself, so this answer adds no value (sorry!)

Comment: Maybe you just can't do what you want. Have you though about getting rid of the spaces in the password? I can't connect with a password that has spaces from Linux.