# Oracle user password with space character in it

Tags: oracle, connectivity, sqlplus

I connected to an Oracle 19c database and executed the following SQL:

```
alter user sys identified by "a b" container=all;
```

It executed successfully. However, after that I can't connect to Oracle using SQLPlus. Below is my trying:

```
oracle:[~]$ sqlplus
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: oracle:[~]$
oracle:[~]$
oracle:[~]$
oracle:[~]$ sqlplus sys/"a b"@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB as sysdba
... (not work)
oracle:[~]$ sqlplus sys/\"a b\"@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB as sysdba
... (not work)
oracle:[~]$ sqlplus sys@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB as sysdba
... (type "a b" without quotes and not work)
```

How can I connect to the database?

Comment: Off the top of my head you can connect as “internal”

Comment: I'm using Oracle 19c and it seems no "internal". <logon> is: {<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | / }
              [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG
              | SYSKM | SYSRAC}] [EDITION=value]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not able to login to oracle using sqlplus utility because username and password contain space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150879/not-able-to-login-to-oracle-using-sqlplus-utility-because-username-and-password/150880)

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus sys/Oracle123@\'localhost/MIN19_O71\' as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jul 30 23:12:19 2019
Version 19.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0

SQL> alter user sys identified by "Oracle 123";

User altered.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0

[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus sys/\""Oracle 123\""@\'localhost/MIN19_O71\' as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jul 30 23:19:25 2019
Version 19.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @Balazs, thanks for your answer! I'm able to log into the database now. I want to confirm that, by running `alter user sys identified by "a b" container=all;`, my password is `a b` or `"a b"`? Thank you!

Comment: @Justalearner https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html "Passwords can contain any single-byte, multibyte, or special characters, or any combination of these, from your database character set, **with the exception of the double quotation mark (")** and the return character."